# vertical centering by position:absolute works only on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I try to set up div with few elements in the middle of section which height is set to 100% of screen height. The problem is solution i have used doesn't work on the other browsers than Google Chrome. I used position:absolute, display:table, margins and top:0, bottom:0;

```js
var section = document.querySelectorAll('section');
  var winh = window.innerHeight;
  header.style.height = winh+'px';
  for (var i = 0; i <= section.length; i++) {
    section[i].style.height = winh+'px';
  }
```

```css
section {
    padding:100px 0;
    position:relative;
    background:#222;
}                                             
section div {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
    display:table; 
}
```

```html
<section class="users">
    <div>
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="count">15 000</div>
        <div class="title">użytkowników</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

On chrome looks perfect, on the other browsers-not. Section height i have declared by JavaScript.

DEMO (view in more than one browser): 
http://wbm-blog.esy.es/projects/timeline/

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical description. What "doesn't work"?

Comment: Please include the JS that sets the height, or add in a height that can reproduce the error.

Comment: @TylerH JS included.

Comment: @Adam you have some undefined variables in your JS. You need to create an [mcve] for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting a height, removing display table and setting margin: auto 0.
The height is needed when centering with the trick top: 0; bottom: 0; margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;

```css
section {
    padding:100px 0;
    position:relative;
}                                             
section > div {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<section class="users">
    <div>
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="count">15 000</div>
        <div class="title">użytkowników</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't know what height this element will have. That's why i used 'display:table' - to detect size automatically.